# How to construct a dataset with lists as columns

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

So I know this should be pretty easy, but I cannot seem to find a solution anywhere, so thanks in advance for your help: 
I have three `Lists` (with numbers as elements) named `lista`, `listb` and `listc` and I want to construct a`dataset` with `columns` "a" to "c", where column "a" contains all elements from "lista" and so on. I then want to be able to use the data in other `dataset` operations (like `Select` or `LinearModelFit` etc.). And, while I don't know if it makes a difference, each list has 1000 elements and all lists are therefore equally long. 
Thanks again for inputs!

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Assuming your lists are the same length you can do `data=Transpose[{lista,list,listc}]` and the proceed as you desire. Try things for yourself. If you get into trouble then you can seek help. Ideally, a minimal working example makes it easier for responders (and may even provide you your own insight). :)

Comment: ResourceFunction["DatasetWithHeaders"]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's take some example lists:

```
lis1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
lis2 = {6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
lis3 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 9};
```

Now you can combine your lists into one list and your headers into a different list:

```
data = {lis1, lis2, lis3};
header = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

To create a dataset just do:

```
Dataset@Map[AssociationThread[header, #] &]@Transpose[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I didn't know about `AssociationThread`, was trying to make it up from scratch like `Association @@@ Transpose[
  {Thread["a" -> lista],
   Thread["b" -> listb],
   Thread["c" -> listc]}]`  This is better

Comment: @JasonB, Yeah, it's a nice little function that makes life easier :)

Comment: +1).Rarely to use `Map` like this.

Comment: @yode, Thanks. Yeah, the operator form is nice sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

If using *Mathematica* version 10.1 or later, we can write:

```
lista = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
listb = {6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
listc = {2, 4, 6, 8, 9};

<| "a" -> lista, "b" -> listb, "c" -> listc |> // Query[Transpose] // Dataset
```

[image: Dataset screenshot]

We can also write:

```
<| "a" -> lista, "b" -> listb, "c" -> listc |> // Dataset // Transpose
```

... but version 10.4 introduced a regression where the resulting dataset loses its type information (the expression works fine in versions 10.1, 10.2 and 10.3).

Comment: +1. I was waiting for you to chime in :). Yeah, I realized the `Dataset` functionality goes through changes all the time with no mention of these changes in the documentation.

Comment: makes it hard to write and reuse code when `Dataset` is such a moving target

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Yes, I tend to avoid `Dataset` myself.  Its main purpose is to visualize data and I find its visualizations to be problematic maybe 50% of the time.  It seems to be overly sensitive to the inferred data types, especially when associations are involved.  And a moving target, as you say.  `Query`, on the other hand, I have grown to like.  It is more stable than `Dataset` and I find the "generalized index notation" to be very expressive.

Comment: @WReach thanks for your 2 cents. I'll spend some more time with `Query`